# How to add autotools-based project as biicode block?

Tags: c++, biicode, log4cpp

I need to use `log4cpp` in my project and I'd like to add this library as biicode block.

I read the documentation and tried to prepare the library for biicode.

I get the source of `log4cpp` from [sourceforge's git here](https://sourceforge.net/p/log4cpp/codegit/ci/master/tree/).
`log4cpp` already has `CMakeLists.txt`, but when I tried to compile it with cmake on ubuntu linux, there was error: `missing file log4cpp/config.h`.

Apparently, `log4cpp` is autotools-based project and needs to run `./autogen.sh` and then `./configure` to prepare project for compilation on Ubuntu linux. When I called this commands, `log4cpp/config.h` file is appeared and I was able to compile project with cmake.

Then I added this code to CMakeLists.txt:

```
if (BIICODE)
    include(biicode.cmake)
    return()
endif()
```

and in biicode.cmake I added this code:

```
# remove tests targets
LIST(REMOVE_ITEM BII_BLOCK_EXES tests_testCategory tests_testConfig tests_testDLL tests_testDailyRollingFileAppender tests_testErrorCollision tests_testFilter tests_testFixedContextCategory tests_testNDC tests_testNDCMain tests_testNTEventLog tests_testPattern tests_testPriority tests_testPropConfig tests_testProperties tests_testPropertyConfig tests_testRollingFileAppender tests_test_convenience tests_testbench tests_testmain)

# remove unnecessary files from lib
LIST(REMOVE_ITEM BII_LIB_SRC
    tests/Clock.cpp
    tests/Clock.hh
    tests/NDCTest.hh
)

ADD_BII_TARGETS()
```

Now I was able to build block with `bii build`. But when [I published this block to biicode](https://www.biicode.com/halex2005/log4cpp) and tried to use it in other sample project, when I run `bii find`, biicode download log4cpp, but not all sources (for example, RollingFileAppender.cpp is not available after downloading).

My sample project that use log4cpp:

```
#include "log4cpp/Category.hh"

int main()
{
    log4cpp::Category::getInstance("application");
    return 0;
}
```

And I was need to add this section to biicode.conf file of sample project:

```
[includes]
    log4cpp/*: halex2005/log4cpp/include
```

So, my questions is:

- How I can prepare autotools-based project to be the biicode block in right way?
- How to run `./auto-gen.sh` and `./configure` on `bii configure` command?
- How to force biicode to download full list of sources for biicode block?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a fork of the git repo with all those changes, so I could have a look and play a bit with it? In any case, the question is maybe more related to the build system of CMake, and how it can handle autotools, that to biicode, that just uses CMake. Maybe look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971921/building-a-library-using-autotools-from-cmake If you have that fork, please tell me and I'll check it.

Comment: Using ExternalProject_Add is interesting, I think I should try this approach. For now I published git repo here: https://github.com/halex2005/log4cpp.